# MongoDB 4.2 combine aggregation pipeline update with array filters

Tags: mongodb

I saw that MongoDB 4.2 introduces aggregation pipeline updates, which allows you to set document fields based on other fields in the document.

Considering the following document

```
{
    ean: "12345",
    orderedQty: 2,
    fulfilledQty: 1,
    "status": "pending"
}
```

I could use the following command to increment the fulfilledQty by 1 and if the orderedQty matches the fulfilledQty set the status accordingly:

```
db.collection.findOneAndUpdate({}, [
  {
    "$set": {
        "orderedQty": {
            "$add": [ "$fulfilledQty", 1 ]
        }
    },  
    "$set": {
      "status": {
        "$cond": {
          "if": { "$eq": ["$orderedQty", "$fulfilledQty"] },
          "then": "fulfilled",
          "else": "pending"
        }
      }
    }
  }
])
```

My question: How would i perform this on an array. Say I have a document like this:

```
_id: "test",
items: [
    {ean: "12345", orderedQty: 2, fulfilledQty: 1, "status": "pending"},
    {ean: "67891", orderedQty: 1, fulfilledQty: 1, "status": "fulfilled"}
]
```

Given I have the params `ean = 12345` and an increase value by 1. How could I target the specific array item with EAN 12345, increase the fulfilledQty by 1 and set the status? I want to only chance the status field and fulfilledQty field and leave the rest of the items array as is. So expected outcome would be:

```
_id: "test",
items: [
    {ean: "12345", orderedQty: 2, fulfilledQty: 2, "status": "fulfilled"},
    {ean: "67891", orderedQty: 1, fulfilledQty: 1, "status": "fulfilled"}
]
```

Comment: I always try to create a targeted update and avoid replacing the entire array. 
 Arrays of sub-documents are effectively acting as a foreign table relationship if thinking in RDBMS terms.  In both cases (Document database vs. RDBMS) you must have a way to uniquely identify the data you wish to update.  In this example is the field 'ean' a key value?  Is it unique in the array of other items?  If not, you may need to consider the array item position index or identify another key.  This feels like an order entry system.  Most have a line item number to key on.

Comment: yes the ean acts as a key here. I know how I can do it with a "classical" array update operator, but not how to do it with the new aggregation pipeline update introduced in 4.2 (or even if it is possible to do this with a aggregation pipeline update)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I found the following workflow (works only for mongodb 4.2+), but it's amazingly verbose…

Given that there are two variables, an item identifier (called `ean`) and a quantity that was shipped (called `fulfilledQty`)

```
collection.update({}, [
  {
    $set: {
      items: {
        $map: {
          input: "$items",
          as: "item",
          in: {
            $mergeObjects: [
              "$$item",
              {
                fulfilledQty: {
                  $switch: {
                    branches: [
                      {
                        case: {
                          $eq: ["$$item.ean", ean]
                        },
                        then: {
                          $toInt: {
                            $add: ["$$item.fulfilledQty", fulfilledQty]
                          }
                        }
                      }
                    ],
                    default: "$$item.fulfilledQty"
                  }
                }
              }
            ]
          }
        }
      }
    }
  },
  {
    $set: {
      items: {
        $map: {
          input: "$items",
          as: "item",
          in: {
            $mergeObjects: [
              "$$item",
              {
                status: {
                  $cond: {
                    if: {
                      $eq: ["$$item.orderedQty", "$$item.fulfilledQty"]
                    },
                    then: "fulfilled",
                    else: "$$item.status"
                  }
                }
              }
            ]
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
]);
```

I used a switch statement since in my use case I have multiple different EANs. Downside is that I had to use a $map operation, so it always iterates over the whole items array.